# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

`below code throwing error as Traceback (most recent call last): bytearray(b'\\x00\\x00)\\xc7') \<class 'bytearray'\> File tesing.py", line 32, in \<module\> formatted_amount = REQ_AMT.decode('utf-8')    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 3: unexpected end of data`

here in the code we are trying to convert req_amt to packed decimal and print the same.

```
import struct

REQ_AMT = '10695'

amount = lambda k: int(k) if k else 0
```

''' converting the value to packed decimal'''
def convert_to_packed(number, size):
formats = {
'2': '>h',
'4': '>i',
'8': '>q'
}

```
    fort = formats[size]
    return bytearray(struct.pack(fort, number))

REQ_AMT = convert_to_packed(amount(REQ_AMT), '4')
print(REQ_AMT, type(REQ_AMT))
''' decoding bytearray to string to print and write into the file'''
formatted_amount = REQ_AMT.decode('utf-8')
record = {
    'REQ_AMT': '{:>4.4}'.format(formatted_amount)
}

print(record)
```

`tried formatted_amount = REQ_AMT.decode('utf-8') but throwing error and formatted_amount = REQ_AMT.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') running fine but formatted_amount values missing xc7.`